JSON is not working, tried import and downloading file?
Downloaded the JSON library jar file and used pasted

{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar"
    ]
}


into Preferences: Open Worspace Settings. I;m pretty sure this should work but I still run into "JSON object cannot be resolved" everytime I run my code. Also should I keep my import JSON statement? Oh Also this is VSCode
Here's my code:
package JavaFiles;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Weather {
    private static final String API_KEY = "216809c91c7a4c19991121927242405";
    private static final String ZIP_CODE = "01773";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String urlString = BASE_URL + "?key=" + API_KEY + "&q=" + ZIP_CODE;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                // Parse the JSON response
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONObject current = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("current");

                // Extract weather information
                String tempC = current.getString("temp_c");
                String condition = current.getJSONObject("condition").getString("text");

                // Display weather information
                System.out.println("Current weather in ZIP code " + ZIP_CODE + ":");
                System.out.println("Temperature: " + tempC + " °C");
                System.out.println("Condition: " + condition);
            } else {
                System.out.println("GET request failed. Response Code: " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


... into Preferences: Open Worspace Settings. Two things about that: 1. You assume everyone knows what that is. Why? There are many IDEs and not everyone uses a. the same one and b. the same one as you. 2. If that's a global setting (and it looks like one), why would you be doing something that's project-specific globally?

@g00se yea you're right, sorry, this is VSCode. I tried to tag it but they said I should only do so for specific questions about VSCode. As for 2, I don't know man I'm a beginner and I hate VSCode but I have to use it.

OK. Next thing: quite apart from the JSON stuff, your code won't compile. You use BufferedReader yet it's not imported. Are you using a Maven type of project?

I'm debugging using JDK I think. Also, Isn't bufferedreader imported up top?

Sorry didn't see it before. The image seems to be of something quite different

https://ibb.co/gTDGJ0n

Yeah sorry uploaded the wrong thing

Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

I was trying to show you my workspace file organization? All the code is already copy and pasted in the original post.

OK, but all I saw was code. You didn't answer my question about what type of project it is, i.e. which build system is being used?

I would urge you to use, when you're using build tools like editors or IDEs, generic build systems, such as Maven or Gradle. THIS Maven version of your code works fine for me in the latest VSCode with java+Maven tools
